# About the definition of extremely disconnected space

Tags: general-topology

a space ‎‎‎$X$‎‎ is said to be extremely disconnected if every open set has an open closure.

I have a question: the closure is a closed set, but in the above definition, it requires the closure is open, which puzzled me a lot.

Comment: A subset of a topological space can be both open and closed

Comment: Correction: such spaces are **extremally** disconnected, not **extremely** disconnected.

Comment: The connected components of a space are both open and closed

Comment: @MPW They need not be open if the space is not locally connected.

Comment: @Gae.S. : Yes, you are right of course. I stand corrected

Comment: It *is* a weird form of disconnectedness. A metrisable space that is extremally disconnected is discrete (and in a discrete space all open sets are also closed, so that *can* happen quite easily) so one doesn't see non-trivial examples very often, except when you start to go deeper in Cech-Stone compactifications and such classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct term is *extremally disconnected*. Every topological space $X$ has two closed set that are open: $\emptyset$ and $X$. If there are more that those, the space is said to be disconnected. Extremally disconnected spaces have a lot of closed sets which are open, specifically all the closures of open subsets must be.

Comment: One might add that a $0$-dimensional space provides yet another point on the scale, being one that has a base of clopen sets. $\Bbb Q$ is an easy example showing that this is weaker than extremal disconnectedness.